# How to download multiple images from firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download multiple images to display in a collection view cell. But downloading just one exceeds the download size. If I upgrade the download size to a higher value the app crashes after 3 or more images are downloaded. How can I download the images and show them on my collection view effectively?

This is my code to upload:

```
    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, uid: String,categoryIndex:Int, spotIndex:Int,completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) ->())) {

let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)/\(categoryIndex)/\(spotIndex).jpg")

guard let imageData = UIImage(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!) else { return }

let metaData = StorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "img/jpg"

storageReference.putData(imageData.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!, metadata: metaData, completion: { metaData, error in
  if error == nil, metaData != nil {
    // success
    storageReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
      guard let downloadURL = url else {
        print("ERROR in image link")
        return
      }

      completion(downloadURL)
    })
  } else {
    // Fail
    completion(nil)
  }
})
}
```

This is my code to download:

```
    // Download image using the category index and spot index to get the correct image
 func downloadImages(folderPath: String, categoryIndex: Int, spotIndex:      Int,success: @escaping (_ image: UIImage)->(), failure:@escaping (_ error:Error)->()) {
let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "\(folderPath)/\(categoryIndex)/\(spotIndex).jpg")
reference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
  if let error = error {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
     failure(error)
   } else {
     if let data = data {
       let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: data)
       success(myImage)
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The compressionQuality should be lower than 0.8
I used 0.25 and seems to be working perfectly.